# Unable to pass multiple parameters on RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Each of my controller methods need to redirect back to the Index page and send the model object they were posted back to the controller with. However, in one instance I need to send an error message along with the model object. Below is the signature of the Index method:

```
    public ViewResult Index(ZipCodeIndex search, string unspecifiedAction = "")
```

Since I only need the error message from one method I made this parameter optional. Here is how I am trying to redirect to the Index from the separate action:

```
        //the parameter 'updateZip' is a model object of type ZipCodeIndex
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { search = updateZip, unspecifiedAction = "Error: Action could not be determined. IT has been notified and will respond shortly."} );
```

All this winds up doing is sending the user back to the original page with the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**EDIT**

After the controller hits the `RedirectToAction` it simply exits the controller without redirecting to the Index method, and the error "Object refrerence not set to an instance of an object" appears on the view.

Comment: I think the problem is "search = updateZip". Please, remove this parameter and try again. Tell us the result.

Comment: @Satpal: ZipCodeIndex is a view model object.

Comment: @KleberBernardo: I need to be able to pass the `updateZip` view model object to the Index method, it's part of it's signature. Also, just in case, I removed it as a redirect parameter and the outcome was the same (no redirect to the Index method an null object reference error message).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass class object in `RedirectToAction`, so remove `search = updateZip` parameter.

If you need it. You can pass it in `TempData` as an alternative

Modify your Action as

```
public ViewResult Index(string unspecifiedAction = ""){
      var search = (ZipCodeIndex)TempData["ZipCodeIndexData"];
      //rest of code
}
```

To redirect

```
TempData["ZipCodeIndexData"] = updateZip;
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { unspecifiedAction = "Error: Action could not be determined. IT has been notified and will respond shortly."} );
```

Comment: The controller does not redirect to the Index method, and on the view I get an error message saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`